# document.getElementsByClassName("x").innerText não está funcionando

Tags: php, html5, echo

Estou tentando usar o `document.getElementsByClassName().innerText` mas ele não substitui o texto contido na classe.

Esse texto vem de um echo php: `echo "<div class=\"life\">$life/$maxlife</div>";`
ficando no html como: `<div class="life">1000/6000</div>`

quando eu uso o `document.getElementsByClassName("life").innerText = "outrovalor"` não acontece nada. No console aparentemente funcionou, mas na pagina a informação não muda. Isso se da ao fato dela ter sido criada no php? Tem como contornar esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName(...)` devolve um array (vetor) de todos os elementos com a class. Faça assim:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("life")[0].innerText = "outrovalor"
```

Assim selecionamos apenas o primeiro, que presumo ser o que quer.

[EXEMPLO](https://jsfiddle.net/ayvoa2am/1/)

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("life")[0].innerText = "outro valor"
```

```html
<div class="life">
valor original
</div>
```

Caso queira mudar em todos os elementos com essa classe:
[EXEMPLO](https://jsfiddle.net/ayvoa2am/2/)

```js
eles = document.getElementsByClassName("life");
for(var i in eles) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("life")[i].innerText = "outro valor " +i;
}
```

```html
<div class="life">
valor 0
</div>
<div class="life">
valor 1
</div>
<div class="life">
valor 2
</div>
```

Comment: Bacana Miguel, era isso mesmo! Obrigado pela ajuda :)

Comment: Ainda bem que resolveu @JacksonAntunes